# jQuery Dialog Setting Radio Checked Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, radio-button

I have a problem where by I want to remember the checked radio button in a jQuery UI dialog popup.

I encountered some strange behaviour so I mocked it up in JSFiddle. The fiddle basically randomly selects one of 3 radio choices when its created. However it soon beings to stop working.

I've tried with and without the line that does removeAttr('checked') as well.

You will need to click open dialog and close it several times to see it stop working. I have been testing this in the latest version of Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/t8kN7/5/

HTML

```
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;">

<input type="radio" class="left" name="rentFrequency" value="1" />
<span class="left">&#160;Monthly&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>

<input type="radio" class="left" name="rentFrequency" value="2" />
<span class="left">&#160;Quarterly&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>

<input type="radio" class="left" name="rentFrequency" value="3" />
<span class="left">&#160;Annualy&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>                                

</div>

<input type="button" name="dialogOpen" value="Open Dialog" />
<input type="text" name="randVal" value="" readonly="readonly" />
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('input[name="dialogOpen"]').click(function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        title: 'Additional Tenancy Information',
        resizable: false,
        width: 530,
        show: { effect:'fade', duration:500 },
        hide: { effect:'fade', duration:400},           
        modal: true,
        close: function (event, ui) {
        },
        open: function (event, ui) {
            var randval=Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1
            console.log(randval); 
            $('input[name="randVal"]').val(randval);
            $('input[name="rentFrequency"]').removeAttr('checked');
            $('input[name="rentFrequency"][value="'+randval+'"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
    });
});
});
```

This is effectively the same code just without the dialog popup and it behaves as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/W6rFh/1/

Just keeping clicking on RUN

Comment: Rather than .attr("checked", "checked"); use the prop function. .prop("checked", true); -- Same with removeAttr

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t8kN7/9/ - using prop seems to solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up on my comment. Change attr instances to prop

```
$('input[name="randVal"]').val(randval);
$('input[name="rentFrequency"]').prop("checked", false);
$('input[name="rentFrequency"][value="'+randval+'"]').prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: I've never need to use prop until today, attr has always served me well. But in this instance it simply has to be prop! :) So many hours wasted but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should only create the dialog once.

In this case I suggest you create the dialog immediately but with the `autoOpen` property set to `false`.

In the click handler you can then just call:

```
$('#dialog').dialog('open');
```

at which point it'll have the same state as when you closed it.

Obviously you should also remove the code to set the random state in the `open:` handler.

Comment: I've just tried this approach here: http://jsfiddle.net/t8kN7/7/

And I still get unexpected behaviour

Comment: get rid of the random stuff in the `open` handler - it gets called every time the dialog is re-opened.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t8kN7/10/ - just using prop instead of attr has solved it. Thanks for you input anyway